# What transition must be applied so that sidebar moves from left to right with ease 0.2s?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What transition must be applied so that sidebar appear to move in from left? Transition value: `all 0.2s ease` I could have done it by making width : 100% and zero on click, but looking for alternatives.
So, basically my query is when I click on hamburger menu sidebar should apparently move from left to right.

https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/QWrvzYe

```js
//for sidebar
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')

const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
//for sidebar
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#sidebar-toggle{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136,169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#sidebar-toggle div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: grab;
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar4 {
  transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar6 {
  transform: translate(0px, -8px) rotate(45deg);
}

.sidebar {
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.open.sidebar {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar-nav{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding:  5px 10px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #007bff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover{
   background: #007bff;
   color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-nav ul li a .icon{
  color:#007bff;
  width:30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar-nav .down_key{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li ul li{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-toggle">
            <div class="bar4"></div>
            <div class="bar5"></div>
            <div class="bar6"></div>
        </div> 
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar'>
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-file-medical-alt"></i></span>
                    <span>Feed</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="feat-btn">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-feather-alt"></i></span>
                    <span>Compose</span>
                    <span class="down_key"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
                    <ul class="feat-show">
                        <li><a href="">Email</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see anything in your CSS which attempts to do this.

Comment: Indeed, you appear to have the value for a `transition` property you want to add, but just haven't added it to the CSS. Have you done so and it didn't work? Show us that. Do you not know where to put it? Try putting it in different places and see if it works. If no place works, ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `transform:translateX(-250px)` to do the animation

```
#mySidebar{
  transition:0.2s;
  transform:translateX(-250px)
}
#mySidebar.open{
  transform:translateX(0)
}
```

https://codepen.io/Guichi/pen/dyewaPP

Comment: This works perfect as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//for sidebar
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')

const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
//for sidebar
```

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#sidebar-toggle{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136,169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#sidebar-toggle div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: grab;
}
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar4 {
  transform: translate(0, 8px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar6 {
  transform: translate(0px, -8px) rotate(45deg);
}

.sidebar {
  transition: 4s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.open.sidebar {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display:flex;
}
.sidebar-nav{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding:  5px 10px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #007bff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li:hover{
   background: #007bff;
   color: #fff;
}

.sidebar-nav ul li a .icon{
  color:#007bff;
  width:30px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sidebar-nav .down_key{
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li ul li{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-toggle">
            <div class="bar4"></div>
            <div class="bar5"></div>
            <div class="bar6"></div>
        </div> 
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar'>
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></span>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-file-medical-alt"></i></span>
                    <span>Feed</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="feat-btn">
                    <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-feather-alt"></i></span>
                    <span>Compose</span>
                    <span class="down_key"><i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
                    <ul class="feat-show">
                        <li><a href="">Email</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can figure out the styling, but here is a working solution, you cannot add a transition to a display:none, you need to use visibility and opacity instead